# Modify name space bindings using wsadmin Jython

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

The task is to modify namespace binding using wsadmin (Jython). 
I have several string bindings for scope server. I plan to list existing bindings; add / modify target binding.

I can list them:

```
for ns in AdminConfig.list( 'NameSpaceBinding' ).splitlines() :
    name = AdminConfig.showAttribute( ns, 'name' )
    stringToBind = AdminConfig.showAttribute( ns, 'stringToBind' )
    print '%s="%s"' % ( name, stringToBind )
```

I can create a new one:

```
server1 = AdminConfig.list('Server')
print AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', server1, [['name', 'binding2'], ['nameInNameSpace', 'myBindings/myString'], ['stringToBind', "This is the String value"]])
AdminConfig.save()
```

1. How to modify existing binding in case there is one?
2. How to delete binding?

I guess it can be done with AdminConfig.modify and AdminConfig.remove.
Links:

1. Doc from IBM: [Configuring namespace bindings using the wsadmin scripting tool](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/txml_namespacebinding.html)
2. Modify binding using jacl: [Configuring namespace binding](http://www.techpaste.com/2011/07/jacl-modify-configuration-application/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I manage to do it myself. I'm not experienced in Jython, but it works. Script requires 4 parameters: target server for scope, binding name, binding value and name in name space:

```
server = sys.argv[0]
bindingName = sys.argv[1]
bindingValue = sys.argv[2]
bindingNameSpace = sys.argv[3]

# Obtain the "simple" server name
def getServerName(s):
    return AdminConfig.showAttribute(s, 'name')

# Add binding
def addBindingsToServer(s):
    for ns in AdminConfig.list( 'NameSpaceBinding' ).splitlines() :
        if bindingName == AdminConfig.showAttribute( ns, 'name' ):
            print "Removing existing binding from Server %s" % getServerName(s)
            AdminConfig.remove(ns)

    # Create binding
    print "Adding binding to Server %s" % getServerName(s)
    print AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', s, [['name', bindingName], ['nameInNameSpace', bindingNameSpace], ['stringToBind', bindingValue]])

# Set server and call function
server = AdminConfig.getid('/Server:'+server+'/')
addBindingsToServer(server)

# Save changes
if (AdminConfig.hasChanges()):
    AdminConfig.save()
```